# Problem with concatenating strings/ getting value from file

Tags: python, csv, sha256, hashlib

I have been writing a program that saves passwords in hash form, but I am trying to get a value from within my file which stores a value for the salt. For some reason, it doesn't seem to work.
Here is my code:

```
hashpass = hashlib.sha256()
salt = ['hbjGVY0Kj07,kbjgvhjb,ZsGhnBi0lp]

for line in login:
            usr = input()
            pas = input()
            log = line.split(',')
            if usr in line:
                x = line
                salt_num = int(x[2])
                setpass = str(pas + salt[salt_num])
                hashpass.update(setpass.encode('utf-8'))
```

I have tried everything, but still no results when I concatenate the string, I just get the value of pas

Comment: The issue is that setpass is just equal to pas, just for clarification

Comment: I have also used log instead of x, same results

Comment: How does the variable `line` look like in each iteration? Could you please share the values in `login` ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply it looks like this:
```
user,68a782faf939dfa370345934d255101926b7f59b3a65ab7db5b0bc6f78ec25e5,0

Comment: This is how `line` in each iteration looks right ?

Comment: Please check the value of `salt` that you have written in code. It cannot be like that. All the values should be inside quotes as string elements.

Comment: no in the code it is correct

Comment: each element is '' seperated

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried and it works. The code you have shared has some issue that I would request you to cross check with original code.

```
import hashlib
hashpass = hashlib.sha256()
salt = ['hbjGVY0Kj07','kbjgvhjb','ZsGhnBi0lp']
login = ["user,68a782faf939dfa370345934d255101926b7f59b3a65ab7db5b0bc6f78ec25e5,0"]

for line in login:
            #print(line)
            usr = input()     # I input "user"
            pas = input()     # I input "qwerty"
            log = line.split(',')
            #print(log)
            if usr in line:
                x = log
                salt_num = int(x[2])
                setpass = str(pas + salt[salt_num])
                print(setpass)
                hashpass.update(setpass.encode('utf-8'))

OUTPUT --> qwertyhbjGVY0Kj07
```

Things I would suggest you to check:

- All the items in list `salt` are in quotes, i.e., as string.
- Login is a list of strings having elements with comma separated value, like I have created.
- change `x=line` to `x=log` inside `if condition`.

Comment: I fixed my program myself but I am getting a different error this time, I will post it as an answer but essentially, I was comparing the hashed password with the user input, I check both variables and they are equal, yet my program says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, but am getting different errors when comparing the variable **hashpass** with **log[1]**, when comparing my program claims that the password is wrong, here is the whole program for reference.

```
login = open('login.csv','r')
def logging():
    atmptcount = 0
    while atmptcount < 3:
        usr = input('Please enter your username: ')
        pas = input('Please enter your password: ')
        hashpass = hashlib.sha256()
        for line in login:
            log = line.split(',')
            if usr.upper() in line:
                print(log[2])
                salt_num = int(log[2])
                setpass = str(pas + salt[salt_num])
                hashpass.update(setpass.encode('utf-8'))
            if usr == log[0] and hashpass.hexdigest() == log[1]:
                print('correct')
                return True

        print(hashpass.hexdigest())
        print(log[1])
        atmptcount = atmptcount + 1
        print('Sorry you have entered your details incorrectly, please try again')
        login.seek(0)
    print('Sorry, you have reached your maximum login attempts!')
    return False
```

I have changed the variable names a bit but its the saem concept